# How to Detect the 'Done' keyboard action on Android via Javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I have a mobile web app, where I  have an HTML5 Input field (type=number).
On the Default Galaxy S3 browser, the 'Done' button on the keyboard does not fire the 'blur' event on that field. (This works fine on the Iphone) .
I need to know how to trap the 'done' event on an Android .
Anyone know how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "Done" do you mean ENTER?

Comment: No, on the keyboard it actually says 'Done', on a 'number' field.

Comment: My Android doesn't have it. Anyway, maybe you could listen to keypress and when 'Done' is pressed you fire the 'blur' event manually (don't forget to stop the event). The keycode for the enter key is 13, you will have to confirm the code of the 'Done' key.

Comment: Did you find out how to capture the done key? I'm having the exact same issue.  Main issue is, the done key doesn't even fire a keyup event.  How can it be captured then?